# C++ BLE Central development for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to develop a C++ DLL in and for Windows 10, that is capable of scanning for, connecting to and exchanging data with a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device.

Can someone please advise on an appropriate library, tutorial or relevant documentation that will enable me to develop a C++ DLL to implement BLE Central functionality.

Comment: I implemented the BLE device and all of the peripheral code for the GATT services on there, so I have a reasonable understanding of the BLE protocol at that level. I have also implemented BLE Central functionality on microcontrollers, but not in Windows. What is the reason you think I would not be able to develop this for Windows, are there not any well documented libraries to do so?

Comment: *"are there not any well documented libraries [...]?"* There are. There is also documentation about what is on-topic for this site (see [help/on-topic]). Availability of documentation doesn't seem to make a difference for you.

Comment: If you think my question was not well suited for where I posted it, then the most useful thing to do would be to suggest where I should have put this, so I can use the site more appropriately in future. However if your time is best spent making unhelpful comments that benefit no-one, then congratulations for having nothing better to do.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn, how this place works. The most useful thing to do with a question that's off-topic is to cast a close-vote. I did.

Comment: I agree with Steve. This is a good question which I am also seeking an answer to. I am looking for C++ BTLE API on Windows (10) and have not found it. I was convinced it did not exist. From some of the responses here I get a renewed hope.I cannot deal with the Assembly nightmare of C#.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the WinRT BLE libraries for C++, which have the same API as if you would write in C#. You for example have https://github.com/urish/win-ble-cpp/tree/master/BLEScanner.

If you want to use the raw C libraries they work as well, but do not have all features: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bad452cb-4fc2-4a86-9b60-070b43577cc9/is-there-a-simple-example-desktop-programming-c-for-bluetooth-low-energy-devices?forum=wdk

Comment: I have had a look around, the only thing I found was references to sample projects for UWP projects that seem to have lots of different BLE functionality bundled together and quite tightly coupled with a GUI. I'm not very familiar with UWP, and couldn't find much documentation to go with the samples, so was having a lot of difficulty stripping it down to what I needed, and how to correctly implement the functionality I needed into a DLL.

I'll have a look at the libraries you've suggested. Thanks.

Comment: The first link you suggested is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, when opening the solution in VS2017 there are a lot of errors, but there are some helpful instruction [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/29/using-ccx-in-desktop-apps/)  However I am unable to determine where the platform.winmd metadata file is stored in VS2017 installation. Any ideas?   Thanks again.

Comment: @Steve: You don't need to use C++/CX to consume WinRT types. A Standard C++ language projection exists: [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt).

Comment: Its 2019 and the Visual Studio C++/WinRT base project is not consistent with Microsoft's documentation on getting started with C++/WinRT. I am vry confused with the new structure (compared to that documented) and don't understand the role of the IDL file. Anyone have any ideas on how to get started with this?